# Backbone.js pattern in Node.js project

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, backbone-views

This question is regarding a pattern that  observed while doing some maintenance work on Node.js project with Backbone.js in front end and Express framework in the backend. Usually, when I use backbone.js in the frontend, I will create routes using Backbone.js router component and then render views based on the route being accessed by the user. For example, if the user is accessing `/user/settings`, it will load the `UserSettingsView` and the associated model(User).
However, in this project, the way the guy who wrote the code is using Backbone.js is quite different. First of all, the router component and Backbone.js routes are not at all used. All the routing is handled by Express itself. When a page loads, it is initially checked wheather a `div` with a specific id is present in the page and if it exists, then a specific Backbone.js view is initiated and that div's id passed to that view as the `el` and the associated model/collection is fetched and rendered. For example, see the code below:

```
$profileEdit = $("#profile-edit");
if ($profileEdit.length) {
  profileEdit = new App.ProfileView({
    el: $profileEdit,
    model: user
  });
}
```

My question is, is this a recommended pattern to use? Are there any disadvantages/advantages of using this pattern over the conventional pattern?

Comment: you could make your question more clear by showing code that is in the frontend and code that is on the server. are you asking how to re-use code between frontend and backend? are you asking how to use the backbone router, or the express router? what I do is using a layout view e.g. http://pipefishbook.com/ch_4/routes/

Comment: My question is not regarding how backbone router is used but is it okay if backbone router is not at all used ?

Comment: sure it is ok - the backbone router is more a navigation system for single page applications. depending on your use case, you might have more server side pages with faster rendering of subviews on the client